# $\mathbb{Z} \times \mathbb{Z} $ is a PID or not?

Tags: abstract-algebra

we know Z is a PID but there exists no ring isomorphism between ZxZ and Z. So based on this observation can we conclude that ZxZ is not a PID ? I dont think we can because if A and B are isomorphic rings then we can say with certainty that both A & B have the same algebraic properties but if they are not isomorphic then it dose not necessarily mean that there can not exist some common property between A and B where some other property/properties are bound to differ. Am I wrong here?

Comment: First of all, ZxZ is not a domain!

Comment: Thanks for your feed back and now please help to to prove this and kindly point out if my conception about the ring isomorphism is true.

Comment: Second, if you wish to show a ring is not a principal ideal ring (PIR), the clearest evidence would be exhibiting an ideal which is not generated by one element.

Comment: You are correct: isomorphic rings have the same (ring-theoretic) properties; non-isomorphic rings may or may not have the same (ring-theoretic) properties. So the fact that ${\mathbb Z}$ and ${\mathbb Z} \times {\mathbb Z}$ are not isomorphic is useless in proving that ${\mathbb Z} \times {\mathbb Z}$ is not a PID.

Comment: (1,1) belongs to ZxZ which is the multiplicative identity with respect to the component wise multiplication. So if ZxZ is not an integral domain then it must posses zero divisor. How to show that ZxZ has zero divisors/

Comment: (Of course, this begs the question, what is a ring-theoretic property actually? Well, that's a property $P$ of rings such that if a ring $R$ has property $P$, then every ring that is isomorphic to $R$ also has property $P$. I'll leave it to the OP to ponder what my comment above then still means.)

Comment: what would $(1,0)\cdot(0,1)=$ be??

Comment: look at this... http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/582699/mathbb-z-times-mathbb-z-is-principal-but-is-not-a-pid

Answer (score 3):

As pointed out in the comments, its not even an integral domain:

$$(1,0) \cdot (0,1) = (0,0).$$

Moral: just because a ring $R$ is an integral domain, does not mean that $R \times R$ is! In fact, $R \times R$ is never a domain unless $R$ is just one-element ring (if you even consider this a ring).

On the other hand, it *is* a PIR (principal ideal *ring*), as a product of PIRs always is (sketch of the proof: let $\mathfrak a=\{(a_i,b_i)\mid i\in I\}$ be an arbitrary ideal in $R^2$; then each $(a_i,0),(0,b_i)$ is in $\mathfrak a$, and if we take for $a$ the element generating the ideal $(a_i\mid i\in I)\unlhd R$ and similarly $b$, then $\mathfrak a=((a,b))$ so we're done).

Comment: Oh thanks man. I am asking such stupid things. sorry

Comment: @SouravChakraborty, no worries bro. Everyone asks silly questions from time to time!

Comment: @SouravChakraborty: I've updated the answer a little to add some additional details.

Comment: @tomasz, good work.