# Prime ideals in a principal ideal ring

Tags: abstract-algebra, commutative-algebra, ring-theory

I know that in a principal ideal DOMAIN every $\neq 0$ prime ideal is maximal. is this also true for just a commutative principal ideal ring? It seems to be true for $\mathbf{Z}/n\mathbf{Z}$ ($>1$, is always a PIR) innit? as every finite integral domain is a field.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> *I know that in a principal ideal DOMAIN every ≠0 prime ideal is maximal.*

Sure...

> *is this also true for just a commutative principal ideal ring?*

Mariano's already provided the fine example of $\Bbb Z\times \Bbb Z$.

> *It seems to be true for $\Bbb Z/n\Bbb Z$ ($n>1$, is always a PIR) innit?*

Yes, that is true. The main reason this is the case is that $\Bbb Z/n\Bbb Z$ is an Artinian ring, and prime ideals of Artinian rings are maximal. (This is a sort of generalization of Wedderburn's little theorem that you mentioned.) The proof is easy: for a prime ideal $P$ in a commutative Artinian ring $R$, $R/P$ is an Artinian domain. But it's easy to show that an Artinian domain is a field. Thus $P$ is maximal.

But these aren't the only examples.

Take an infinite direct product of fields: the prime ideals are again maximal. This time, the reason is that the ring is a [von Neumann regular ring](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Von_Neumann_regular_ring). This example is not even Noetherian!

The best you can say is this: for a commutative ring $R$, all prime ideals of $R$ are maximal iff $R/J(R)$ is von Neumann regular and $J(R)$ is nil, where $J(R)$ is the Jacobson radical of $R$.

This absorbs almost all the previous cases mentioned. For Artinian rings, $R/J(R)$ is semisimple (hence VNR) and $J(R)$ is nilpotent (hence nil.) For the product of fields case, $J(R)=\{0\}$ and $R$ is VNR. Finally, $\Bbb Z\times \Bbb Z$ has zero Jacobson radical, but it isn't VNR, so it is consistent with the statement I gave.

Notice though that the PID case is not captured, namely because we had been excusing the $\{0\}$ ideal from being maximal! If we go back to thinking about domains for which *nonzero* primes are maximal, we have what are called [$1$-dimensional](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Krull_dimension) domains. The class of $1$-dimensional domains includes the class of [Dedekind domains](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dedekind_domain), so there are more than just PID's there.

So, to summarize and return to commutative PIRs whose nonzero prime ideals are maximal, two things can happen:

1. $\{0\}$ is prime, so you have a PID which is $1$-dimensional.
2. $\{0\}$ isn't prime, $R$ is Noetherian with nil radical, hence nilpotent radical, so by [Hopkins-Levitzki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hopkins-Levitzki_theorem), the ring is an Artinian PIR.

Answer (score 3):

[The ring $\mathbb Z\times\mathbb Z$ is a principal ideal ring.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/582699/mathbb-z-times-mathbb-z-is-principal-but-is-not-a-pid/582911#582911)

Comment: But its prime ideals are maximal

Comment: @Sergio No they aren't. Using the notation $\lhd$ for ideals of rings, if $I\lhd R$ and $J\lhd S$ then $I\times J\lhd R\times S$. Moreover the prime ideals of $R\times S$ are precisely $\mathfrak{p}\times S$ where $\mathfrak{p}$ is a prime ideal of $R$, and $R\times \mathfrak{q}$ where $\mathfrak{q}$ is a prime ideal of $S$, and these "product ideals" are clearly nonzero as long as $R$ and $S$ aren't trivial.

Comment: Therefore if $R$ has some non-maximal prime ideal then $R \times S$ has a nonzero prime ideal that isn't maximal - if $\mathfrak{p} \subsetneq I \subsetneq R$ then $0 \subsetneq \mathfrak{p} \times S \subsetneq I \times S \subsetneq R \times S$. Similarly if $S$ has any non-maximal prime ideal.

In the case $R = S = \mathbb{Z}$, $\mathbb{Z}$ has the non-maximal prime ideal $\{0\}$, and hence $\{0\} \times \Z$ is a non-maximal (nonzero) prime ideal, since $0 \subsetneq \{0\} \times \mathbb{Z} \subsetneq n\mathbb{Z} \times \mathbb{Z} \subsetneq mathbb{Z} \times \mathbb{Z}$ (for any $n > 0$).