# Is $\mathbb R \times \mathbb Q$ a principal ideal domain

Tags: abstract-algebra

I have a similar question to this one:

[$\mathbb Z\times\mathbb Z$ is principal but is not a PID](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/582699/mathbb-z-times-mathbb-z-is-principal-but-is-not-a-pid)

Is $\mathbb R \times \mathbb Q$ a principal ideal domain/ring (that is - is every ideal in $\mathbb R \times \mathbb Q$ a principal ideal)?

Comment: It is not a domain, so pointless to call them PIDs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you read the answers given in the link, you will see that they apply to every PID$^{(1)}$ $A$ and $B$ and not only to $\Bbb Z \times \Bbb Z$.

So, every ideal in $R=\mathbb R \times \mathbb Q$ is a principal ideal, i.e. it is a PIR. (Actually, there are only $4$ ideals because $\mathbb R$ and $\mathbb Q$ are fields).

However, $R$ is not a PID since it is not a domain : $(1,0) \cdot (0,1)=(0,0)$, as Joanpemo's answer shows.

---

$^{(1)}$ or even to every PIR, that is: $A,B$ PIR $\implies A \times B$ PIR.

Answer (score 5):

It's not even a domain: $\;(1,0)\cdot(0,1)=(0,0)\;$.

Comment: Is a principal ideal domain and principal ideal ring the same thing? (I am not learning math in english so I got confused from using english sources)

Comment: Well, $\;\Bbb Z/n\Bbb Z\;$ is a principal ideal ring which is not a field for composite $\;n\;$, and it is not a domain.

Comment: No, this is not the same. In a PIR, the ideals are just assumed to be principal. In a PID, we also assume the ring to be an integral domain, that is a commutative ring s.t. $xy=0 \implies x=0$ or $y=0$.

Comment: so $\mathbb R \times \mathbb Q$ is a PIR? And we could prove also that a finite product of PIR's also is a PIR

Comment: @Max : yes, that is moreless what I wrote in my answer.