# Make sure that $m \mathbb{Z}\times n\mathbb{Z}$ is an ideal of $\mathbb{Z} \times \mathbb{Z} $

Tags: abstract-algebra, ideals, maximal-and-prime-ideals

good night!

> Make sure that $m \mathbb{Z}\times n\mathbb{Z}$ in the ring $\mathbb{Z} \times \mathbb{Z} $ is an ideal.

I couldn’t come up with a convincing answer. Could you help me? Thanks in advance!

I know that ideal is a product $R\times S$ of rings with identity has the form $I\times J$, where $I, J$ are ideals in $R, S$ respectively. Moreover, since $\mathbb{Z}$ is a principal ideal domain, every ideal of $ \mathbb{Z} $ has the form $m\mathbb{Z}$ for some $m$. Hence every ideal of $ \mathbb{Z}\times \mathbb{Z} $ has the form $m\mathbb{Z} \times n\mathbb{Z}$ for soem $m, n \in \mathbb{Z}.$

But, Is it true?

Comment: You need to show it's group under addition and closed under multiplication. Can you show that $m\mathbb{Z}$ is an ideal of $\mathbb{Z}$?

Answer (score 1):

First, make sure that $m\mathbb Z$ and $n\mathbb Z$ are ideals of $\mathbb Z$. How would you do that? You just take generic  elements $a\in m\mathbb Z$ and $b\in\mathbb Z$ and check that $ab\in m\mathbb Z$, right?

Now, assuming that operations on products are defined coordinate-wisely, you can use the same method to prove that $I=m\mathbb Z\times n\mathbb Z$ is an ideal of $R=\mathbb Z\times\mathbb Z$. In fact, a generic element of $I$ has form $(a,a')$ with $a\in m\mathbb Z$ and $a'\in n\mathbb Z$, and for any $(b,b')\in\mathbb Z\times\mathbb Z$, their product is defined as
$$ (a,a')(b,b')=(ab,a'b'). $$
I believe that you're able to continue by yourself from here :)

Comment: @Ottavio_Bartenor

$(1,0)(0,1)=(0,0)$, right?

Is this example considered an ideal?

Comment: Yeah, $(1,0)(0,1)=(0,0)$, but what are you referring to by "is this considered an ideal"?

Comment: Sorry, is a principal ideal domain?

Comment: You mean $\mathbb Z\times\mathbb Z$? No, it can't be a PID, it's not even an integral domain (and you just proved why; the product of two non-zero elements can be zero)

Comment: Actually, it is *principal*, though. You might want to check here, for example: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/582699/mathbb-z-times-mathbb-z-is-principal-but-is-not-a-pid